How to make CloudFront to deliver an old version of the page?
How to make CloudFront to always deliver an old version of the page, not asking the origin again, unless this query was never received before? (well, with some timeout, like 3600sec after which a request to the origin can be done again)
My purpose is to decrease the number of (paid) requests to the origin (api.OpenAI.com).
I suspect, this can be done with Lambda Edge, but how to retrieve an old version of the page in Lambda Edge?

Hm, this can be done by joining two CloudFront instances: The first removes Cache-Control header, the second does caching. But that's at least inconvenient. Can this be made simpler?

Wouldn't you just change the Default or Minimum TTL? Managing how long content stays in the cache (expiration) - Amazon CloudFront

@JohnRotenstein I already set minimum TTL to 3600 sec, but it does not "overcome" Cache-Control policy of the OpenAI server.
